# Running airflow with docker-compose behind nginx proxy (using nginxproxy/nginx-proxy and nginxproxy/acme-companion)

Tags: airflow

I am running airflow 2 with docker-compose (works great) but I cannot make it accessible behind a nginx proxy, using a combo of [nginxproxy/nginx-proxy](https://hub.docker.com/r/nginxproxy/nginx-proxy) and [nginxproxy/acme-companion](https://hub.docker.com/r/nginxproxy/acme-companion).

Other projects work fine using that combo (meaning, that combo is working fine) but it seems that I need to change some airflow cfgs to make it work.

The airflow docker-compose includes the following:

```
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  build: ./airflow-docker/
  environment:
    AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__BASE_URL: 'http://abc.def.com'
    AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__ENABLE_PROXY_FIX: 'true'
  [...]
services:
  [...]
  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    expose:
      - "8080"
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=abc.def.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=abc.def.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=some.email@def.com
    networks:
      - proxy_default # proxy_default is the docker network the nginx-proxy container runs in
      - default
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      [...]
    [...]
  [...]

networks:
  proxy_default:
    external: true
```

Airflow can be reached under the (successfully encrypted) address, but when one opens that url it results in the "Ooops! Something bad has happened." airflow error, more specifically a "sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: session" error, even though it works fine when not behind the proxy.

What am I missing?